# ACCESS 2010 confirm record before appending table

Tags: ms-access

i am new to access so appreciate being patient with me.
i  create my database and i am entering data (view form) to the table. is there a possibilty when finishing data entry to get a "CONFIRM" question wether writing data (record) to table or ignore it  ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Before_Update / Before_Insert events

Answer (score 1):

Simply place the following code in the forms before update event:

```
If MsgBox("Submit this data?", vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then

   Cancel = True

End If
```